# What is the right way to adopt NSCopying Protocol?

Tags: objective-c

I have a question about NSCopying protocol in Objective-C. Please refer to the following code:

Super class:

```
@interface superClassA : NSObject <NSCopying>
```

Sub class:

```
@interface subClassB : superClassA <NSCopying>
```

I think to myself: I can override the super's `-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone` method.

So do I need to declare the `<NSCopying>` protocol in subclass (`subClassB`)?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to redeclare that subClassB conforms to the NSCopying protocol. A subclass is said to conform to all of the protocols that its parent conforms too.

Comment: Yep, to make it short: **classes inherit protocols**.